# How to create ZigZag pattern using set of Points

Tags: javascript, math, svg, drawing, geometry

I am working in svg and want to create a pattern using given set of points. My zigzag pattern is 'Equilateral Triangle'. I am using 'Path' in svg to create this. issue is that i am unable to find exact 'mid point' between two points to create 'Equilateral Triangle'.

My required result is:-

[image]

Results i am getting when line is not horizontal:-

[image]

**My code:-** 
let say i have array of points

```
function createZigzag(points){
    var x, y, lx, ly, mx, my, path;
    var height=5;
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        x = points[i].x;
        y = points[i].y;
        if (i === 0)
        {
            path = 'M ' + (x) + ' ' + (y) + ' L';
            continue;
        }
        lx = points[i - 1].x;
        ly = points[i - 1].y;
        mx = (lx + x) / 2;
        my = (ly + y) / 2;

        my-=height;

        path += ' ' + (mx) + ' ' + (my);
        path += ' ' + (x) + ' ' + (y);
    }
    return path;
}
```

Above logic works fine if points belong to a 'straight horizontal line'. Else, it does not 
generate my required path. 
Problem lies in calculation of 'mx,my' (midpoints). I have searched alot, applied line equation etc, but unable to solve this.

Comment: Try the new answer I posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding your `height` to `my`, you need to add a vector perpendicular to the line segment.  The key here:  the 2-D vector `(dx,dy)` is perpendicular to `(dy,-dx)`.

Specifically, instead of:

```
my -= height;
```

you should do something like:

```
scale = sqrt(0.75);
mx += scale * (y - ly);
my -= scale * (x - lx);
```

The `scale` constant above has been chosen to yield an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have straight (possibly rotated) lines then you could easily do this as a filled rectangle using a triangle pattern.

Something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 480 480">
    <pattern id="pat" viewBox="0 0 2 4" width="0.04" height="1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <polyline points="-1,4 0,0 1,4 2,0 3,4" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.1" fill="none"/>
    </pattern>

    <rect width="50%" height="20" fill="url(#pat)"/>
    <rect width="50%" height="20" fill="url(#pat)" transform="rotate(25) translate(20 20)"/>
</svg>
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Mct/).

Answer (score 0):

Why have you set my-=height..?
Because I hope that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: height takes midpoint higher to make a triangle between these points.

Comment: Since the line is not horizontal any more, so you will have to compute height accordingly in both the axis, that is using the slope of the guiding line. Compute increments in both the axis and use them to decrement y and increment x.